# Sesquilinear forms - How does positiveness imply hermitianity?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, positive-definite, sesquilinear-forms

In my mathematical methods for physics course notes I find this:

```
A positive sesquilinear form is nondegenerate and Hermitian
```

The first statement is trivial: a positive form is such that

$\begin{cases}\hat{B}(x)\geqslant0\ \forall\,x\in X\\\hat{B}(x)=0\iff x=0\end{cases}$

Where $\hat{B}(x)=B(x,x)$ is the quadratic form associated to the sesquilinear form $B$.

The second condition gives us the nondegenerate part. If the form wasn't nondegenerate, there would be a $x\in X, x\ne0$ such that $B(x,y)=0\ \forall\,y\in X$. That means than even $B(x,x)=\hat{B}(x)=0$, which gives us an absurd with the fact $x$ must be $0$.

What I can't get is how the positivity (probably, the first condition of it) can cause the Hermitianity.

$\hat{B}(x)\geqslant0\ \forall\,x\in X\Rightarrow B(x,y)=\overline{B(y,x)}?$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y \in X$, then we have
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{k=0}^3 i^k B(x+i^k y, x+i^ky) &= B(x+y, x+y) - B(x-y,x-y)  \\
& \quad + i \left[B(x+iy,x+iy) - B(x-iy, x-iy) \right] \\
&= 2 B(y,x)+2B(x,y) + 2B(x,y)-2B(x,y) + 2 B(y,x) \\
&= 4B(y,x).
\end{align*}
Since $ B(x+i^k y, x+i^ky) \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
\begin{align*}
4\overline{B(y,x)} &=\sum_{k=0}^3 (-i)^k B(x+i^k y, x+i^ky) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^3 i^k B(y+i^kx,y+i^kx)\\
&=B(x,y)
\end{align*}